# Android FileProvider for CACHE DIR : Failed to find configured root that contains

Tags: android, caching, android-7.0-nougat, android-fileprovider, android-7.1-nougat

I found so many links which is related to FileProvider, but I didn't found solution for **cache directory**

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root
>   that contains `/data/data/pkg name/cache/1487876607264.png`

I want to use it for **CACHE DIRECTORY**, How can I give path in **provider**.

```
<paths>
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."  />
</paths>
```

I used it as :

```
File file = new File(context.getCacheDir(), System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png");

Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", file);
```

Its working fine if I give application folder path, but not working with **Cache Directory.**

Any Help?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Use `<cache-path>`, not `<external-path>`. See [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html#SpecifyFiles).

Comment: i've use `<cache-path name="my_cache" path="." />` but still ` Failed to find configured root that contains`. what should i do?

Comment: @zihadrizkyef: That implies that the `File` that you are trying to use is not in `getCacheDir()` or a subdirectory of `getCacheDir()`.

Comment: @CommonsWare you are a true asset to stack. I feel like I personally owe you 57 beers.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I use the same name for two different paths. The only working path is the last one. So make sure to specify unique name for each path.